# I need to use hangfire in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-4.5, hangfire

I need to use hangFire in ASP.NET MVC but I can't call backgroundService in ASP.NET MVC.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bp2HT.png)

In .NET Core, I register it in the `Startup` file:

```
builder.Services.AddHostedService<RecurringJobsService>();
```

I don't know how to register it in ASP.NET MVC running on the .NET Framework v4.5

Comment: Have you read? https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/getting-started/aspnet-applications.html